# Autofac WCF injection on reflection

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, reflection, autofac

I have N validators on my aplication but a client doesn't use all validators, I got by procedure all classes that my current client will need to instantiate.

My Business layer:

```cs
public class MyClass
{
    public void MyMethod(int idClient)
    {
        //This array is returned by a procedure passing idClient
        string[] validatorsName = { "ValidatorName", "ValidatorName2" };

        foreach (string name in validatorsName)
        {

            IValidator validator = (IValidator)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(name));
            //Error. I need pass the INameDB;

            validator.Process();
        }
    }
}
```

My Interface:

```
public interface IValidator
{
    void Process();
}
```

The Validators:

```
public class ValidatorName : IValidator
{
    INameDB nameDB;

    public ValidatorName(INameDB nameDB)
    {
        this.nameDB = nameDB;
    }

    public void Process()
    {
        nameDB.AnyThing(pedidoId);
    }
}

public class ValidatorName2 : IValidator
{
    INameDB2 nameDB;

    public ValidatorName(INameDB2 nameDB)
    {
        this.nameDB = nameDB;
    }

    public void Process()
    {
        nameDB.AnyThing2(pedidoId);
    }
}

public class ValidatorName3 : IValidator
{
    INameDB2 nameDB;

    public ValidatorName(INameDB2 nameDB)
    {
        this.nameDB = nameDB;
    }

    public void Process()
    {
        nameDB.AnyThing2(pedidoId);
    }
}
```

On Global, I could register all validators and with the `IList<IValidator>`, so I would remove from the list the validators that I will not need.

```
 string[] validatorsName = { "ValidatorName", "ValidatorName2" };
 validators = validators .Where(p => validatorsName .Contains(p.GetType().Name)).ToList();
```

but I have a lot of classes, it would register this no need.

My Global:

```
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{

    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ContainerBuilder builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterType<NameDB>().As<INameDB>();
        builder.RegisterType<NameDB2>().As<INameDB2>();

        //builder.RegisterType<ValidatorName1>().As<IValidator>();
        //builder.RegisterType<ValidatorName2>().As<IValidator>();
        //builder.RegisterType<ValidatorName3>().As<IValidator>();

        AutofacHostFactory.Container = builder.Build();
        //AutofacHostFactory.Container.Resolve<IList<IValidator>>();
    }
}
```

My question is how can I detect the interface `INameDB` or `INameDB2`, get the instance on `Autofac` and use on `Activator.CreateInstance`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some days, I could code the solution:

My main class, I create a method to injection the validators list:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private IList<IValidator> listValidators;

    public void MyMethod(int idClient)
    {
        ExecuteValidations(idClient);
    }

    private void ValidatorInjection(int idClient)
    {
        listValidators = new List<IValidator>();
        //This array is returned by a procedure passing idClient
        string[] validatorsName = { "ValidatorName", "ValidatorName2" };
        foreach (string name in validatorsName)
        {
            IValidator validador = (IValidator)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(name));
            listValidators.Add(validador);
        }
    }

    private void ExecuteValidations(int idClient)
    {
        ValidatorInjection(idClient);
        RunValidatorsList();
    }

    private void RunValidatorsList()
    {
        foreach (var validator in listValidators)
        {
            validator.Process();
        }
    }
}
```

My validators, I needed get the interface database instance on container with `INameDB2 db = AutofacHostFactory.Container.Resolve<INameDB2>();`:

```
public class ValidatorName : IValidator
{
    public void Process()
    {
        INameDB db = AutofacHostFactory.Container.Resolve<INameDB>();
        db.AnyThing(pedidoId);
    }
}

public class ValidatorName2 : IValidator
{
    public void Process()
    {
        INameDB2 db = AutofacHostFactory.Container.Resolve<INameDB2>();
        db.AnyThing2(pedidoId);
    }
}

public class ValidatorName3 : IValidator
{
    public void Process()
    {
        INameDB2 db = AutofacHostFactory.Container.Resolve<INameDB2>();
        db.AnyThing2(pedidoId);
    }
}
```

On Global, I did a way that I don't need add line to register a new class that `IValidator` implement:

```
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ContainerBuilder builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterType<NameDB>().As<INameDB>();
        builder.RegisterType<NameDB2>().As<INameDB2>();

        string assembly = "MY_ASSEMBLY";
        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.Load(assembly)).Where(t => t.IsAssignableTo<IValidator>()).AsImplementedInterfaces();

        AutofacHostFactory.Container = builder.Build();
    }
}
```